# Getting Correct Info in Console, But Angular 2 Login Not Working as Expected

Tags: javascript, mongodb, angular

I have a login in my Angular 2 app, and I have been converting it from using a fake backend (which works) to connect to our mongoDB-based API instead.

This is the login function I am using in the authentication service:

```
login(username: string, password: string) {
    const u = encodeURIComponent(username);
    const p = encodeURIComponent(password);
    this._url = `https://api.somesite.com/v0/staff/login/${u}/${p}?apikey=somekey`;
    console.log(this._url);
    return this.http.post(this._url, JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password }))
        .map((response: Response) => {
            // login successful if there's a jwt token in the response
            const user = response.json();
            if (user && user.token) {
                // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
                localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
            }
        });
}
```

In my login component I am subscribing like this:

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
                console.log('User logged in as: ' + this.model.username);
            },
            error => {
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
            this.authenticationService.username = this.model.username;
}
```

When I try this, and log to the console "this_url", I get what I would expect. For instance, if the user typed in "billsmith" for username, and "parisnow" for password, I see this in the console for "this_url":

```
https://api.somesite.com/v0/staff/login/billsmith/parisnow?apikey=somekey
```

Furthermore, I can type that url directly into the browser address window and see data (when the username and password correctly correspond to actual records in our database). So it's accessing the correct info in that sense.

But in the console I get a "404" error for that generated url. It also doesn't "do anything". In other words, it doesn't correctly redirect to the main component as it did with the fakeBackend-enabled login. And the only thing that's different now is the url that I am calling (because I'm connecting to our actual API now, as opposed to a fake backend provider).

FYI, the url when using the fake backend looked like this:

```
return this.http.post('/api/authenticate', JSON.stringify({ username: username, password: password}))
```

What am I missing here?

By the way, this is how things look on the server side re: our mongoDB:

```
exports.byLogin = function(req, res, next) {

    let ioOnly = false, username, password;
    if (_.isUndefined(req.params)){
        ioOnly=true;
        username = req.username;
        password = req.password;
    }
    else {
        username = req.params.username;
        password = req.params.password;
    }

    staff.findOne({username: username, password: password}, function(err, doc) {
        if (err) { if (!ioOnly) { return  next(err) } else { return res(err)}}
        else if(doc) ((!ioOnly) ? res.send(doc) : res(doc));
        else ((!ioOnly) ? res.sendStatus(204) : res(doc));
    });
};
```